# How can I get my code to conditionally loop back to its start?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm very much a beginner at Java. I am in my second week of my first course at college and already love programming. I've been trying to use some of the stuff I've learned in lecture and lab to create a little game but I'm having some issues.

The code is as follows:

```
public class MathGame {
public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println("~~~~Welcome to ____!~~~~~");
    System.out.println("Press 'S' to continue");

    char startGame;
    char correctStart = 'S';
    startGame = TextIO.getChar();
    if (startGame == correctStart){

        System.out.println("Both you and the computer will start with 20 lives");   //Game explanation
        System.out.println("Use different move options to reduce your opponents life");
        System.out.println("First one down to zero loses!");
        System.out.println("OK here we go:");


        int lifeTotal1 = 10;
        int lifeTotal2 = 10;
        int turnNum = 0;
        turnNum ++;

        System.out.println("Start of turn: " + turnNum);
        System.out.println("Your life total is " + lifeTotal1 + " your opponents life total is " + lifeTotal2);     //Starts turn
        System.out.println("Select a move:");
        System.out.println("Press 1 to do 3 damage");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to do a random amount of damage");
        System.out.println("Press 3 to heal 2 damage");

        int userAttack1;
        userAttack1 = TextIO.getInt();

        if(userAttack1 == 1){           //User attack #1 selected
            lifeTotal2 -=3; 
        }
        if(userAttack1 == 2){           //User attack #2 selected
            double random1 = Math.random();
            if (random1 > 0 && random1 <= .2){
                lifeTotal2 -= 1;
            }
            if (random1 > .2 && random1 <= .4){
                lifeTotal2 -= 2;
            }
            if (random1 > .4 && random1 <= .6){
                    lifeTotal2 -= 3;
            }
            if (random1 > .6 && random1 <= .8){
                    lifeTotal2 -= 4;
            }
            if (random1 > .8 && random1 <= 1){
                        lifeTotal2 -=5;
            }
        }

        if (userAttack1 == 3){
            lifeTotal1 += 2;
        }

    System.out.println("End of turn");
    System.out.println("Your current health is " + lifeTotal1);
    System.out.println("Your opponents current health is " + lifeTotal2);

    if (lifeTotal1 <= 0){
        System.out.println("Game over, you lose");
    if (lifeTotal2 <= 0){
        System.out.println("Game over, you win");
    }
        }else{
```

After the else statement I've literally just copy and pasted the code to start a new turn until one of the life totals gets down to 0. This is an issue though because it creates a finite number of turns. How can I get my code to keep looping until a life total reaches zero?

I understand the game is no where near complete. I would appreciate any help!
Thanks so much

Comment: A `while-loop` is the usual method to loop your code.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop is useful to iterate until a condition is met. This will loop until either life total reaches 0.

```
//Game set up code before your loop

while (lifeTotal1 > 0 && lifeTotal2 > 0) {

    // Any code in here will repeat until one life total hits 0

}

//Code here to handle the game being over
```

Comment: @b1boss no problem. Accepting my answer is all the thanks I need!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you iterate from 1 to 10 and at some iteration you need to start the loop again, then you can do something like this

```
for(int i=1 ;i<=10; i++){
   if(condition) {
      // This will make sure that the loop starts from the beginning.
      i=0;
   }
}
```

Comment: OMG this loop will be infinite, what do you suggest?

Comment: @Andremoniy: I just put that the condition is for explanation. In Real program there will be real condition

Comment: So where exactly would I add this into my code? Is there any way to make the loop contingent on the players life totals rather than an integer? Oh and thanks so much for the help

Comment: @b1boss: I can only give a hint . You need to solve the entire program. I hope you got the logic behind the sample program I wrote for you